# How can I load unlimited previous week from moment.js in my calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to load previous week when i click on previous month button infinite. I'm using this code but It's giving previous month for one time only. After one click It does not work. I'm using this code

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if(e == 1) {
        currentWeek = currentWeek + 1;
    }else if (e == -1){
        currentWeek = currentWeek - 1;
    }else {
        currentWeek = 0
    }

    var startOfWeek, endOfWeek;
    if(currentWeek == 0){
     startOfWeek= moment().isoWeekday(1).startOf('week');
     endOfWeek = moment().isoWeekday(1).endOf('week');
    //  console.log(startOfWeek);
    }else if(currentWeek > 0) {

        startOfWeek = moment().add(currentWeek, 'weeks').startOf('week')
        endOfWeek = moment().add(currentWeek, 'weeks').endOf('week')
    }else{
        startOfWeek = moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week')
        endOfWeek = moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('week')
    }
    var days = [];
    var day = startOfWeek;

    while (day <= endOfWeek) {
        days.push(day.toDate());
        day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a simple fiddle?

Comment: Where are you defining `currentWeek`?

Comment: currentweek is defined above as currentweek=0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be very careful with Moment.js. Most of its functions change the original object. On the other hand you should keep your current week saved in a variable (I suppose this is what `currentWeek` in your code should do). Your problem is that you create a new moment() each time, which will be set to the current week, and you only have the possibility to move 1 week forward or backwards. Here is my solution:

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udo3qctn/)

**Javascript code:**

```
// Global variable to track the week 
var timeTracker = moment();

function getDays(e) {
    var days = [];
    if (e == 0) {   
        timeTracker = moment();
    } else {
        timeTracker.add(e, 'weeks');
    }

    // Find start and end of week
    var startOfWeek= timeTracker.clone().startOf('isoWeek');
    var endOfWeek = timeTracker.clone().endOf('isoWeek');

    var days = [];
    var day = startOfWeek;

    while (day.isSameOrBefore(endOfWeek)) {
        days.push(day.toDate());
        day = day.add(1, 'days');
    }

    return days.join('<br />'); 
}

function displayPrevWeek() {            
    document.getElementById('daysOfWeek').innerHTML = getDays(-1); 
} 
function displayCurrentWeek() {      
    document.getElementById('daysOfWeek').innerHTML = getDays(0); 
} 
function displayNextWeek() {    
    document.getElementById('daysOfWeek').innerHTML = getDays(1); 
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<label>Week:</label>
<div id="daysOfWeek">
</div>
<div>
<button onclick="displayPrevWeek()">Previous week</button>
<button onclick="displayCurrentWeek()">Current week</button>
<button onclick="displayNextWeek()">Next week</button>
</div>
```

**Important note:** I see that you want Monday to be the first day of the week. I do not know why `moment().isoWeekday(1).startOf('week')` does not return Monday as first day, but Sunday. Instead I use
`moment().startOf('isoWeek')` Perhaps this is the current way of doing it (see the release notes for Moment.js).

**Important note 2:** This code support jumping a different amount of weeks forward or backwards (no need to be only 1 per time). Just call `getDays` with different parameter that 1 or -1.

Comment: I need sunday as first day of week so I apply startOf('week') instead of startOf('isoWeek')